# Android Dialog black screen for second before showing

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, themes

I have a class, WebViewDialog.
There is a method in it like this:

```
suspend fun show(
    url: String,
    uxContext: Context
): Boolean {
    val dialog = Dialog(uxContext.fragmentActivity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_web_view)

    val webView = dialog.findViewById<SSOWebView>(R.id.web_view)
    webView.loadUrl(url)
    dialog.show()
}
```

This gets called from our public-facing API.
The issue is when it launches the dialog, the screen is black for a second before showing the web view.
If I do Theme_Light_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen it is white, if I do Theme_Dark_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen it is black. If I set it to transparent like I did above it is also black.
I am curious how can I fix this. I have tried most of the fixes online, like setting the theme to transparent or setting some flags but nothing seemed to fix it.

I want it to be transparent or something so you see the current screen before it launches the dialog to a full screen.
If I set the height and width of the dialog to be smaller, the black screen is only set to that size, so it is for sure just the dialog causing it to be black.